# Appending to a configuration file

Tags: bash

I am creating a script which updates hosts in an application, the config file for each host looks like that below. The script generates the hosts correctly but I need to append every } with a comma , except the last host.

I have tried numerous things but the closest I have got is putting the hosts content on a single line and running a IFS statement against it. Im also not sure how best to approach this, can anyone advise?

```
{
"cmd": "ssh user@webserver",
"inTerminal": "new",
"name": "webserver",
"theme": "basic",
"title": "Webserver",
}
```

example of what I am trying to achieve

```
{
"cmd": "ssh user@webserver",
"inTerminal": "new",
"name": "webserver",
"theme": "basic",
"title": "Webserver",
},
{
"cmd": "ssh user@db",
"inTerminal": "new",
"name": "db server",
"theme": "basic",
"title": "db",
},
{
"cmd": "ssh user@mail",
"inTerminal": "new",
"name": "mail server",
"theme": "basic",
"title": "mail server",
}
```

Comment: The [XY](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) problem is asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem.

Comment: `printf '%s\n' 'g/^}$/s/$/,/' 's?^},$?}?' ,p Q | ed -s file.txt`

Comment: Does that file use JSON format? If so, try to look at `jq` tool. https://stedolan.github.io/jq/ It is like sed for json.

For example appending could be like
```bash
cat file.json | jq '. += [{cmd: "ssh user@webserver", inTerminal: "new"}]'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do things like:

```
#!/bin/sh

for f in $(generate-host-list); do
        read -d \000 c < "$f"
        list="$list${list+,
}$c"
done
echo "$list"
```

If you are just writing to a file that can be simpler (no need for the `read`, just `cat` the file).  Similarly, if you don't care about munging whitespace, you could do `list="$list${list+,}$(cat "$f")`.  If you are using `bash` or some other shells you can do non-portable things like `+=` to clean it up.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
sed '$q; s/^}$/},/' <in_file >out_file
```

The above sed command works as follows: First check if you've reached the last
line, and if so quit. Otherwise, it'll check if the only character on the line
is `}`, and if so replace it with `},`.